# Instagram API - Dynamic redirect for WP Plugins

Tags: api, redirect, dynamic, parameters, instagram

i´m working on an instagram feed plugin for wordpress. This plugin will shows the own instagram feed with many options.

The problem: to get the access token and user data i have to declare a static redirect url in my code and on the instagram client settings page. Both must be excact the same..so the problem begins :D People who use this plugin have another url than my redirect url...and doesn´t work..

Would be awesome, if you have a solution for this thing. I heard about state parameters..maybe would be this the answer?